# Ethernet magnetics, discrete vs integrated: inductance value

Tags: ethernet, inductance, magnetics

I recently made a change to an EtherCAT-over-Ethernet design, where I moved from using an RJ45 with integrated magnetics to a low-profile connector with discrete magnetics because of size constraints.

The connector to be used is a Würth [7499010121A](https://www.we-online.com/katalog/datasheet/7499010121A.pdf). Both designs are using a [KSZ8081MNX](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002202C.pdf) PHY.

I then moved on to using discrete chokes and transformers based on reading an app note from TDK (I think) ([ACM2012-900-2P-T002](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/emc/emc/cmf_cmc/catalog/cmf_commercial_signal_acm2012_en.pdf)) and ([ALT4532M-201-T001](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/transformer/transformer/lan/info?part_no=ALT4532M-201-T001)), configured like so:

[image]

They system works, but I am experiencing some frame drops at the host computer, so I've been exploring anything that has changed (quite a lot has changed mechanically). The current theory is that the main issue is temperature related, or that it is at least a significant contributor.

What I noticed when looking back over this portion of the design is that the open-circuit inductance specified for the discrete transformer is min. 200 μH, compared to the 350 μH of the previous connector:

[image]

The PHY also specifies 350 μH as the min. inductance.

[image]

As the transformer is listed as suitable for 100BASE-TX, I expect this all might be a bit of a red herring, but hopefully I can learn something from this at least.

My questions:

- Am I interpreting this correctly?
- What does the 350 μH of the connector actually refer to?
- Is it a fair comparison? How might I discover what I have?
- If the inductance is lower than is needed, what might the effects be?

Comment: Can you define Zin and Zout?

Comment: The circuit does not look right. Why there are 1kV caps on the PHY side, and why the 75 ohm resistors are directly connected to same ground, as the point of an Ethernet interface to use transformers to begin with is to have isolation between devices. Can you specify which end is the PHY end and which end is the RJ45 connector pin end and how does that schematic connect to PHY and connector?

Comment: You need to show a side-by-side comparison of both old and new circuits. The new circuit looks incompatible with the old one as far as I can tell. You also need to disclose the connections in the new circuit to the J1-J8 pins. Much more detail needed.

Comment: Yikes, you might be right Justme. I know where to come for my next design review. I will post clearer schematics later.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I too and looking at using discrete magnetics and want to know whether the lower inductance value was the cause of the problems. Let me know and have a great day. Jason

Comment: This kind of problem needs careful review, testing with full+100m cable, and some type of validation that the network isn’t at fault rather than assume it’s hardware right away.

Answer (score -1):

You want to have the highest L possible for the current, you need to improve your CMRR from SMPS PSRR noise.

Details to follow;